# Spring AOP Pointcut does not trigger

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, aop, aspectj

I am new to Spring and AOP. I am trying this simple thing where I have created a custom annotation which when placed before any method should execute some code.
This is the annotation I created

```
    // Declares a custom annotation that validates json
    @Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
    @Target(ElementType.METHOD)
    public @interface JsonSchemaAnnotation {
    }
```

Next I created the Spring Aspect class which holds the logic

```
@Aspect
public class UpdateUIMetadataInterceptor {

@Pointcut("execution(public * com.fico.cardinal.cm.*.*(..))")
public void anyPublicMethod() {
    System.out.println("Running");
}

@Before("anyPublicMethod() && @annotation(jsonSchemaAnnotation)")
public void validateJson(ProceedingJoinPoint pjp) throws Throwable {
    System.out.println("Running");  
}

}
```

And this is my simple test class

```
public class ValidationTest {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("spring/configuration.xml");
    String jsondata = "{\"id\": \"EXPENSE_REPORT\",\"properties\": {\"transactionType\": \"EXPENSE_REPORT\"},\"sections\": []} ]}";
    ValidationTest test = new ValidationTest();
    test.jsonValidationTest("dummy", jsondata);
    ((AbstractApplicationContext) context).close();


}

@JsonSchemaAnnotation
public void jsonValidationTest(String dummy, String jsondata) {
    System.out.println("Success");

}
```

The problem is my spring aop never gets triggered. I have included a bean in my `configuration.xml`

```
<aop:aspectj-autoproxy>
    <aop:include name="UpdateUIMetadataInterceptor" />
</aop:aspectj-autoproxy>
<bean id="updateUI"      class="com.fico.cardinal.cm.interceptor.UpdateUIMetadataInterceptor" />
```

Can anyone point out what I am missing?

Comment: I have followed [this](http://eggsylife.co.uk/2010/02/03/spring-annotation-based-aop-and-intercepting-the-ball/) blog

Comment: You create your `ValidationTest` object using new, so it's not managed by Spring. You have to have it as a bean in your application context and then obtain reference to it through your `context` variable

Comment: Created it via bean just now. Still no improvement. I think I am missing something more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have several problems with your code:

1. You should create your `ValidationTest` object as a bean managed by Spring and not using new
2. `<aop:include name="UpdateUIMetadataInterceptor" />` should be `<aop:include name="updateUI"/>`; you can actually just stick with `<aop:aspectj-autoproxy/>` for simplicity here
3. `ProceedingJoinPoint` is not supported for before aspects, so remove it; you can use `JoinPoint` instead if you need access to arguments
4. `JsonSchemaAnnotation jsonSchemaAnnotation` parameter should be present for `validateJson` method of your aspect, as pointed out by [frant.hartm](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31986565/2106575)

Comment: Yep this should do it, I have missed the wrong include name :-)

Comment: I need to use the parameters of the annotated methods. That's why I have used `ProceedingJoinPoint`. How am I supposed to get access to the parameters without using that?

Comment: I have edited my code according to your suggestions. (Check question) But still my aspect class is not triggered.

Comment: You can use `JoinPoint` instead of `ProceedingJoinPoint`. Can you please update all of the code in your question? I tried to run an app configured just like yours and advice is triggered. Also include contents of your pom.xml

Comment: Check out my edited code. I have also included the `pom.xml`

Comment: I don see any beans named `test` in your `configuration.xml`. Did you forget to update it?

Comment: Ohh yes. Updated it now. Btw I am just checking for the print statement to test whether the advice is triggered or not. I hope that is the way to test it.

Comment: Ok, I give up :) [Here](http://codeshare.io/HZSNl) is the code I used to test this, it's basically the same as yours as I copypasted most of it. But it definitely works for me locally, output is 'Running\nHello'. Check it out, maybe you can spot what's different

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/86900/discussion-between-rockydgeekgod-and-dmitry-kuskov).

Comment: Found the bug. It was a stupid import error. But this solution works like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need either fully qualified name or a parameter in the method:

FQN:

```
@Before("anyPublicMethod() && @annotation(your.package.JsonSchemaAnnotation)")
public void validateJson(ProceedingJoinPoint pjp) throws Throwable {
    System.out.println("Running");  
}
```

Parameter:

```
@Before("anyPublicMethod() && @annotation(jsonSchemaAnnotation)")
public void validateJson(ProceedingJoinPoint pjp, JsonSchemaAnnotation jsonSchemaAnnotation ) throws Throwable {
    System.out.println("Running");  
}
```

Source: http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html#aop-pointcuts

(and you also need to use the bean, as Dmitry Kuskov pointed out

Comment: I tried both fully qualified name

`@Before("anyPublicMethod() && @annotation(com.fico.cardinal.cm.interceptor.JsonSchemaAnnotation)")`

and parameter

`public void before(ProceedingJoinPoint pjp, JsonSchemaAnnotation jsonSchemaAnnotation) throws Throwable`

But it does not work in either case